# Dependent variable as an odds ratio

Tags: regression, odds-ratio

I have a pretty simple question to ask. I have a regression model where the dependent variable is a calculated odds ratio. This is different from a binomial model that outputs odds ratio.

My problem is that numerous observations have an odds ratio of 0. Taking the log of zero is not possible so I plan to add a small amount. The issue seems to be if I do LN(0 + .01) vs LN (0 + 1), then my estimates seem to be heavily biased against groups that have numerous odds ratios of zeros.

For example, I have the following two groups of odds ratios
.3
.2
0
0
.4
0

and for the other group
.3
.5
.2
.1
.5
.2

the estimate for the two different groups seems shifts drastically depending on how I handle odds ratios of 0.

Comment: Why can't you just use the raw odds ratio as the predictor? Why are you trying to take the log of it?

Comment: I made a critical error in the formulation of my question, the odds ratio is the dependent variable

Comment: In what weird sort of [context](http://arfer.net/w/statqgl) do you have odds ratios as a DV?

Comment: Sounds like a meta-analysis of rare events. What you need is the raw data that lead to the odds ratios and then you can do something sensible about it.

Comment: @Björn I agree, I've also only seen odds ratios as some kind of dependent variable in meta-analyses. However, I wanted to note it is possible to perform meta-analyses based on odds ratios and standard errors, without having the raw source data. Admitted, having the raw data would give you more options to account for, for example, heterogeneity between studies.

Comment: As to the question, as Kodiologist states, without context it is hard to recommend anything specific. Furthermore, I cannot see how a study would conclude an odds ratio of **0**. Are you sure these are not missing? Additionally, on the scale of odds ratios, adding a small amount (0.01) to a zero is actually setting a very strong 'protective effect'. i.e. the resulting odds ratio of 0.01 means the odds of the outcome are a 100 times smaller for someone with the exposure than for the reference group! Then again, setting it to 1 would mean no effect at all. Pretty extreme corrections I'd say...

Comment: @IWS an odds ratio of zero is a problem in the sense that no symmetric normal approximation for N(log odds ratio, SE) for the naive estimate of 0 (that lies on the boundary of the parameter space) makes any sense, the same would be if the estimate of the OR would be infinity. An estimate of 0 for the OR means that you had zero events in one group and small sample approximations via log OR +- SE are really poor for the binomial distribution.

Comment: @Björn +1 we agree completely. However, wouldn't the estimate be impossible to calculate as you have to divide by 0 somewhere (nonsensical as you say)? I can see entering people entering a '0' as per some convention, but that would really means the study could not provide this statistic. Hence I asked whether the zeroes are truly zeroes (which, again, would be nonsensical), or actually missing for some reason (e.g. because of having 0 events in one of the groups).

Comment: @IWS: Zeros can be totally legitimate and can still provide information. E.g. one clinical trial with 10/100 patients on drug with an event versus 0/50 on a placebo with an event still tells you something. It is just not so easy to estimate an odds ratio based on that trial alone, but once you have other trials and use a better method (e.g. exact conditional logistic regression or Firth's penalized likelihood LR or a hierarchical model with a binomial likelihood for each arm etc.), this trial may contribute to an overall estimate.

Comment: @Björn Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61547/discussion-between-iws-and-bjorn).

Comment: Let me give a little context to what is being done. The odds ratio is looking at the rate of proportionality between rates of occurrences between two groups. In a perfect world, the two groups should have the same proportional number of incidents (i.e. a 10% rate). The odds ratio should be 1. Now, group 1 has a higher incident of non occurrence rate which leads to an inflation of zeros.